# No virtual method getLayoutInflater

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to code an app that downloads data of some events from an online MySQL database and writes it into my android app. Right now, what i'm trying to do is just testing if downloading the name of the event works, but i keep getting this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getLayoutInflater()Landroid/view/LayoutInflater; in class Lcom/suspicio/appfisio_business/FrammentoCorsi; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.suspicio.appfisio_business.FrammentoCorsi' appears in /data/app/com.suspicio.appfisio_business-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk)
                  at com.suspicio.appfisio_business.FrammentoCorsi$EventoAdapter.getView(FrammentoCorsi.java:204)
```

which points to the line:

```
listViewItem = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.frammento_corsi, null, true);
```

Here's my code (it's a fragment):

**FrammentoCorsi.java:**

```
public class FrammentoCorsi extends Fragment {

public static final int CODE_GET_REQUEST = 1024;
public static final int CODE_POST_REQUEST = 1025;

public FrammentoCorsi() { //Vuoto
}

boolean isUpdating = false;
View rootView;
List<Evento> eventoList;
ListView listView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frammento_corsi, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewEventi);
        return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    eventoList = new ArrayList<>();
    readEventi();

}

private void readEventi() {
    PerformNetworkRequest request = new PerformNetworkRequest(Api.URL_READ_EVENTI, null, CODE_GET_REQUEST);
    request.execute();
}

private void refreshEventoList(JSONArray eventi) throws JSONException {
    //clearing previous heroes
    eventoList.clear();

    //traversing through all the items in the json array
    //the json we got from the response
    for (int i = 0; i < eventi.length(); i++) {
        //getting each hero object
        JSONObject obj = eventi.getJSONObject(i);

        //adding the hero to the list
        eventoList.add(new Evento(
                obj.getInt("id"),
                obj.getString("titolo"),
                obj.getString("inizio"),
                obj.getString("fine"),
                obj.getInt("categoria"),
                obj.getString("link"),
                obj.getString("luogo")
        ));
    }

    //creating the adapter and setting it to the listview
    EventoAdapter adapter = new EventoAdapter(eventoList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

//inner class to perform network request extending an AsyncTask
public class PerformNetworkRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    //the url where we need to send the request
    String url;

    //the parameters
    HashMap<String, String> params;

    //the request code to define whether it is a GET or POST
    int requestCode;

    ProgressBar barra = (ProgressBar) getView().findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    //constructor to initialize values
    PerformNetworkRequest(String url, HashMap<String, String> params, int requestCode) {
        this.url = url;
        this.params = params;
        this.requestCode = requestCode;
    }

    //when the task started displaying a progressbar
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        barra.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    //this method will give the response from the request
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        barra.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(s);
            if (!object.getBoolean("error")) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), object.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                refreshEventoList(object.getJSONArray("eventi"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //the network operation will be performed in background
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();

        if (requestCode == CODE_POST_REQUEST)
            return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(url, params);


        if (requestCode == CODE_GET_REQUEST)
            return requestHandler.sendGetRequest(url);

        return null;
    }
}

class EventoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Evento> {

    List<Evento> eventoList;

        //constructor to get the list
    public EventoAdapter(List<Evento> eventoList) {
        super(getActivity(), R.layout.frammento_corsi, eventoList);
        this.eventoList = eventoList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View listViewItem = convertView;
        if (listViewItem == null) {
            listViewItem = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.frammento_corsi, null, true);
        }

        //getting the textview for displaying name
        TextView textViewName = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.nomeeventocalendario);

        //the update and delete textview
        //ImageView textViewUpdate = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.notifica);
        //ImageView textViewDelete = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.link);

        final Evento evento = eventoList.get(position);

        textViewName.setText(evento.getTitolo());

        return listViewItem;


    }

}

}
```

And its resource file **frammento_corsi.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         tools:context="com.suspicio.appfisio_business.FrammentoCorsi">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewEventi"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nomeeventocalendario"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Can you help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  this

```
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
 listViewItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.frammento_corsi, null ,true);
```

Instead of this

```
 listViewItem = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.frammento_corsi, null, true);
```